# $a > b+1 \Rightarrow a>x>b$?

Tags: logic, inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers, integers

If I have $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $$a > b+1 $$
It is assured that $\exists\space x \in \mathbb Z: a>x>b$

Does this property have some special name?
How can this be proved?

This idea isn't intuitive to me. Infact, it feels untrue.
If so, when is it true.

Please help.

Comment: I guess taking $\lfloor b+1\rfloor$ will work though not sure

Comment: @kingW3: So, by what you're saying: $x \equiv \lfloor b+1\rfloor \equiv \lceil a \rceil$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a-b-1\gt 0$, there exists a real number $\alpha\gt 0$ such that $a=b+1+\alpha$. Then, since there exists an integer $m$ such that $m-1\le b\lt m$, we have
$$b\lt m\lt m+\alpha\le b+1+\alpha =a,$$
which implies that $m$ satisfies $b\lt m\lt a$.

Comment: You are using the fact that every real number lies in between integers? Why did you choose $m-1\le b\lt m$ instead of $m-1\lt b\le m$ ?

Comment: I use that fact that every real number is either an integer or lies in between integers. You can use $m-1\lt b\le m$ if you want. You can get the same result if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Draw this property in the Real Line.
By the hypotessis, you have that a-b > 1, so, you can find an integer that is between them, in fact, integer part of b as your x works for your problem, in any case.

Comment: Only if $b$ is not itself an integer!

Comment: sorry, is the integer part of b, plus 1

Answer (score 0):

The referenced proof is correct, but it can be easily made more clear.

Suppose $r,s \in \mathbb R$ and $r \gt s$ then $r - s \gt 0$. Then $\frac1{r-s} \gt 0 \implies \frac2{r-s} \gt 0$. (That was the change.)

Now, there exists an integer $p$ such that $$p \gt \frac2{r-s} \implies p(r-s) \gt 2 \implies pr \gt ps +2$$

Then there exists another integer $q$ such that
$$pr \gt q \gt ps \implies r \gt \tfrac{q}{p} \gt p$$